# Is Microsoft Forms adequately secure to collect personal health information?

Tags: security, encryption, microsoft-forms

I want to make a survey on a website using Microsoft Forms. Patients would input personal health information into this form, so I want it to be secure.

The Microsoft website indicates that Microsoft Forms is HIPAA and BAA compliant, which sounds great; however, when I dig deeper, I don't really find what I want to see in plain English.

Can information submitted over Microsoft Forms be read by someone other than me, the website owner?

Comment: That's probably better asked on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DavidPostill They didn't want it! I believe the answer is quite clear to someone who has some knowledge of the area. My issue is I'm not that familiar with the information that Microsoft presents.